# Loop through name specific columns to check the value (Next Level)

Tags: r, loops

I want to achieve the following:

1. loop through all CHECK columns, sometimes there are more (up to 20). The same goes for data (will definitely more than 3 observations). feel free to use my variables CHECKnum, CHECKstart or CHECKend
2. check whether anything starting with A is in it, if yes, return the column name, else return CHECK0
3. this was previously achieve by getting exact match of A001, but i need a str_detect like kind of function

sample data

```r
mydf <- data.frame(case = c(1, 2, 3),
                   id = c(10, 11, 12),
                   CHECK1 = c("A001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK2 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK3 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"),
                   CHECK4 = c("Z001", "B001", "A001"),
                   CHECK5 = c("Z001", "B001", "C001"))
```

Trial:

```r
#Select the columns to check
cols <- grep('CHECK', names(mydf), value = TRUE)
#Compare the value
#mat <- mydf[cols] == 'A001'
mat <- str_dect(mydf[cols], 'A')
#Find the column name where the value exist in each row
mydf$result <- max.col(mat)
#If the value does not exist in the row turn to `NA`.
mydf$result[rowSums(mat) == 0] <- NA
mydf

#  case id CHECK1 CHECK2 CHECK3 CHECK4 CHECK5 result
#1    1 10   A001   Z001   Z001   Z001   Z001 1
#2    2 11   B001   B001   B001   B001   B001   <NA>
#3    3 12   C001   C001   C001   A001   C001 4
```

I want it to show something like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox38L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sapply` with `startsWith` to find out rows that start with `'A'`.

```
cols <- grep('CHECK', names(mydf), value = TRUE)
#Compare the value
mat <- sapply(mydf[cols], startsWith, 'A')
#Find the column name where the value exist in each row
mydf$result <- cols[max.col(mat)]
#If the value does not exist in the row turn to 'CHECK0'.
mydf$result[rowSums(mat) == 0] <- 'CHECK0'
mydf

#  case id CHECK1 CHECK2 CHECK3 CHECK4 CHECK5 result
#1    1 10   A001   Z001   Z001   Z001   Z001 CHECK1
#2    2 11   B001   B001   B001   B001   B001 CHECK0
#3    3 12   C001   C001   C001   A001   C001 CHECK4
```